# Spark asynchronous job fails with error

Tags: apache-spark, asynchronous, spark-submit

I'm writing code for spark in java. When I use `foreachAsync` spark fails and gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.`

In this code:

```
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext("local","MyAppName");
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeTextFiles = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("somePath");
    wholeTextFiles.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, String>>() {
        public void call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

It works fine. But in this code:

```
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext("local","MyAppName");
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> wholeTextFiles = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("somePath");

    wholeTextFiles.foreachAsync(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, String>>() {
        public void call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

It returns error. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `foreachAsync` returns a Future object and when you leave a function, the spark context is closed (because it's created locally).

If you call `get()` on `foreachAsync()` then main thread will wait for the Future to complete.